# Find power value from exponential growth?

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

If I have `1 * (1 + .01)^100 = 2.7` for example, how would I figure out what the power of `X` is if I have the value. I have `1 * (1 + .01)^X` How would I get X if I know it's 2.7?

Comment: Your question is confusing, but I think the answer you are looking for is using logarithms

Answer (score 0):

If $ 1 \cdot (1 + .01)^x=2.7$ then

\begin{align} &(1.01)^x=2.7 \\ 
 &\ln(1.01)^x=\ln (2.7)   \quad\quad  \text{Apply natural log both side. }\\
 &x\ln(1.01)=\ln (2.7)   \quad \quad \text{Since } \ln(a^x) =x\ln(a)\\
&x=\frac{\ln (2.7)}{\ln(1.01)} \quad \quad \quad \quad \text{Divide both sides by $\ln(1 .01)$ }\\
&x\approx 99.82\\
\end{align}

Comment: How can I do this with numbers larger than 1?

Comment: @burner8268 The process is the same . If there is another number than 1 multiplying from left , first take that to the other side by dividing by that number both sides . Other than that, everything is the same